# The equal to sprintf in c#

Tags: c#, .net, c

I am searching for the equal from.
C code:

```
    char msg[100];
    int LED=2;
    sprintf(msg,"1,%d,1,0",LED);
   //msg is now (1,2,1,0)
```

but in C# the old function `sprintf` from c disappears.
How can I do this in C#

Comment: `1,2,1,1` shouldn't be `1,2,1,0` ?

Comment: yes sry it shoud be i change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent would be `String.Format`:

```
int LED=2;
string msg = String.Format("1,{0},1,0",LED);
```

As a side note, C# is not a "new" version of C (or C++).  It is a completely different language with similar syntax but a completely new framework.

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat similar:

```
string msg;
int LED = 2;
msg = String.Format("1,{0},1,0", LED);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? As in

```
string mgs = String.Format("1,{0},1,0", LED);
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically want `String.Format`. It's not the exact same thing but it accomplishes a similar purpose.